# How can perform an pandas apply method on Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, data-analysis

The problem is that i am tackling to convert Organisations by NumberOfSpaceMission. If number of space mission smaller than particular value the new column important_organisation will be 'Other countries' otherwise it will be organisation's name which is index of dataframe.

[image: Our Dataframe]

```
def editCountry(row):
    if row['NumberofSpaceMission'] < 10:
       return 'Other organisation'
    return row.index

new_df['important_organisations'] = new_df.apply(editCountry)
```

I tried some structure and ways using apply method.Moreover i employed with map function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a default value:

```
new_df['important_organisations'] = 'Other organisation'
```

Then use pandas filtering to get the index values & assign to the respective rows:

```
new_df.loc[new_df['NumberofSpaceMission']>=10,'important_organisations'] = new_df.loc[new_df['NumberofSpaceMission']>=10].index
```